# PHP - variable issue

Tags: php, variables

I have recently constructed a form (see below) and i managed to write a php script where i set up the mail to be sent when i press the submit button from the form. The problem is that in php script in the $message variable the only things that are sent by email are the string and not the variables such as $name, $customer_number etc.

Could anybody be kind enough to point out the error to me please?

The form:

```
<form name="bookingForm" method="post" action="send_dates.php">
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">

<tr>
<td>Booking From</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="fromDate" id="fromDate" size="20"></td>

<td>To</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="toDate" id="toDate" size="20"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input name="name" id="name" size="30"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td width="20px">Telephone</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input name="customer_telephone" id="customer_telephone" size="30"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td width="20px">Email</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input name="customer_email" id="customer_email" size="30"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onClick="document.getElementById('ResetForm').click();">
    <input type="reset" name="ResetForm" id="ResetForm" value="Reset"></td>
</tr>
</table>
    </form>
```

PHP script send_data:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$fromDate = $_POST["fromDate"];
$toDate = $_POST["toDate"];
$email = $_POST["customer_email"];
$telephone = $_POST["customer_telephone"];

// Mail of recievers
$to = "ucjulian@gmail.com";

// Contact subject
$subject ="Reservation Enquiry from $name";

// Details
$message="
From: $name
Email: $customer_email
Telephone: $customer_telephone
--------------------------------------------------------------
Reservation date from: $fromDate to: $toDate ";

// Mail of sender
$mail_from="$customer_email";

$rev = mail($to,$subject,$message);

if($rev) {
    echo 'booking request has been sent!';
}
else {
    echo 'something has gone wrong. Please try again!';
} ?>
```

Comment: What's the result when you do a var_dump on $_POST?

Answer (score 6):

You're defining the variables as `$email` and `$telephone`, but using them as `$customer_email` and `$customer_telephone`, respectively.

Update the name usage in either area and you should be set.

Comment: what a stupid mistake, i kept putting in the input box names instead of the variables :-S

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong variable name. Replace

```
From: $name
Email: $customer_email
Telephone: $customer_telephone
```

with

```
From: $name
Email: $email
Telephone: $telephone
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have register_globals off [likely to be thhis way] you'd better use $telephone instead of $customer_telephone in your $message